# how to iterate list in C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

The accumulated version of the above triangle is:

[image]

Example Input Data: A short input file might contain the following:

```
var products = new List<Products>()
{
    new Products { ProductName = "Comp", OriginYear = 1992, DevelopmentYear = 1992, IncrementalValue = 110.0 },
    new Products { ProductName = "Comp", OriginYear = 1992, DevelopmentYear = 1993, IncrementalValue = 170.0 },
    new Products { ProductName = "Comp", OriginYear = 1993, DevelopmentYear = 1993, IncrementalValue = 200.0 },
    new Products { ProductName = "Non-Comp", OriginYear = 1990, DevelopmentYear = 1990, IncrementalValue = 45.2 },
    new Products { ProductName = "Non-Comp", OriginYear = 1990, DevelopmentYear = 1991, IncrementalValue = 64.8 },
    new Products { ProductName = "Non-Comp", OriginYear = 1990, DevelopmentYear = 1993, IncrementalValue = 37.0 },
    new Products { ProductName = "Non-Comp", OriginYear = 1991, DevelopmentYear = 1991, IncrementalValue = 50.0 },
    new Products { ProductName = "Non-Comp", OriginYear = 1991, DevelopmentYear = 1992, IncrementalValue = 75.0 },
    new Products { ProductName = "Non-Comp", OriginYear = 1991, DevelopmentYear = 1993, IncrementalValue = 25.0 },
    new Products { ProductName = "Non-Comp", OriginYear = 1992, DevelopmentYear = 1992, IncrementalValue = 55.0 },
    new Products { ProductName = "Non-Comp", OriginYear = 1992, DevelopmentYear = 1993, IncrementalValue = 85.0 },
    new Products { ProductName = "Non-Comp", OriginYear = 1993, DevelopmentYear = 1993, IncrementalValue = 100.0 },
};
```

This example file contains two triangles – one for a product called ‘Comp’ and one for a product called ‘Non- Comp’. The first row contains column headings, and the subsequent rows contain the data, so, for example, for accidents occurring on the Non-Comp product in 1990, 45.2 was paid in 1990, 64.8 was paid in 1991 and 37 was paid in 1993.

The output file corresponding to the above input file would be:

```
1990, 4 
Comp, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 110, 280, 200 
Non-Comp, 45.2, 110, 110, 147, 50, 125, 150, 55, 140, 100
```

The first line gives the earliest origin year (i.e. 1990) and the number of development years (in this case ranging from 1990 through to 1993 i.e. 4).

After the first line, there is a line for each triangle. The first field in the line gives the name of the product. The subsequent fields are the accumulated triangle values.

The two classes I have built so far to achieve this.

`Products`:

```
public class Products : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _ProductName;
    int _OriginYear;
    int _DevelopmentYear;
    double _IncrementalValue;

    public string ProductName
    {
        get
        {
            return _ProductName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_ProductName != value)
            {
                _ProductName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ProductName");
            }
        }
    }

    public int OriginYear
    {
        get
        {
            return _OriginYear;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_OriginYear != value)
            {
                _OriginYear = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("OriginYear");
            }
        }
    }

    public int DevelopmentYear
    {
        get
        {
            return _DevelopmentYear;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_DevelopmentYear != value)
            {
                _DevelopmentYear = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DevelopmentYear");
            }
        }
    }

    public double IncrementalValue
    {
        get
        {
            return _IncrementalValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_IncrementalValue != value)
            {
                _IncrementalValue = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("IncrementalValue");
            }
        }
    }

    void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

`ProductViewModel`:

```
class ProductViewModel
{
    OleDbConnection Conn;
    OleDbCommand Cmd;
    List<Products> Productsobj;

    public ProductViewModel()
    {
        string ExcelFilePath = @"ProductData.xlsx";
        string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ExcelFilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=True";
        Conn = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
    }
    /// <summary>  
    /// Method to Get All the Records from Excel  
    /// </summary>  
    /// <returns></returns>  
    public async Task<List<Products>> ReadRecordFromEXCELAsync()
    {
        Productsobj = new List<Products>();
        await Conn.OpenAsync();
        Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        Cmd.Connection = Conn;
        Cmd.CommandText = "Select * from [Sheet1$]";
        var Reader = await Cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            Productsobj.Add(new Products()
            {
                ProductName = Reader["Product"].ToString(),
                OriginYear = Convert.ToInt32(Reader[" Origin Year"]),
                DevelopmentYear = Convert.ToInt32(Reader[" Development Year"]),
                IncrementalValue = Convert.ToDouble(Reader[" Incremental Value"])
            });
        }
        Reader.Close();
        Conn.Close();

        return Productsobj;
    }

    public void DisplayData()
    {
        int maxYear = Productsobj.Max(t => t.OriginYear);
        int minYear = Productsobj.Min(t => t.OriginYear);
        DateTime max = new DateTime(maxYear, 1, 1);
        DateTime min = new DateTime(minYear, 1, 1);
        int years = Years(min, max);
    }

    public int Years(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        return (end.Year - start.Year) +
            (((end.Month > start.Month) ||
            ((end.Month == start.Month) && (end.Day >= start.Day))) ? 1 : 0);
    }

    public void CalculateAccumulativeData()
    {
        var paymentdata = from p in Productsobj
                          group p.ProductName by new { };

        foreach (var data in paymentdata)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data.Key);
            foreach (var listing in data)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\t{0}", listing);
            }
        }
        Productsobj.ForEach(item => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.OriginYear + "," + item.IncrementalValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is far too broad for Stack Overflow.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have been trying use Linq and group by option but no success yet. I have got data in excel sheet which i have imported n saved in List<products>.. cant find a way iterating it by group by product name option

Comment: @RulezS - You need to improve this question. You've give sample data in an image - we can't use this data as source without typing it all all - we're not your data entry temps. Please replace the image with compilable C# source for the data. Also you haven't explained how the data gets transformed into the output. Where do all the `0`'s come from in `Comp`? And you've suggested a type `Product` is being used without providing the definition for the type. And ideally you should show your code that you've tried - even if it works or not. This question will get closed unless you fix it.

Comment: the data is in excel format which i have imported into my datagrid. I have a product class which im using to bind data to. the data will be saved in List<products>. 
the sample data is 
Product, Origin Year, Development Year, Incremental Value 
Comp, 1992, 1992, 110.0 
Comp, 1992, 1993, 170.0 
Comp, 1993, 1993, 200.0 
Non-Comp, 1990, 1990, 45.2 
Non-Comp, 1990, 1991, 64.8 
Non-Comp, 1990, 1993, 37.0 
Non-Comp, 1991, 1991, 50.0 
Non-Comp, 1991, 1992, 75.0 
Non-Comp, 1991, 1993, 25.0 
Non-Comp, 1992, 1992, 55.0 
Non-Comp, 1992, 1993, 85.0 
Non-Comp, 1993, 1993, 100.0

Comment: @RulezS - Please **edit your question**. Please include **compilable C# code** for the source. Please provide the **class definition for `Products`**. Please explain the **transformation rule** to produce the output.

Comment: @RulezS: This should get you started: http://ideone.com/uMmoJU

Comment: @mellamokb : thank you so very much.,....really appreciated. let me try that out n ill get back you,.thanks again

Comment: @RulezS - I've edited the question to a state which I think it is now a good question. I've voted to re-open.

Comment: @RulezS - I've tried answering this question for my own sanity and I have to say the rule for transforming the data is still very unclear. I can't understand at all what you mean.

Comment: @mellamokb: thank you your solution helped me to achieve what i wanted to u. thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that output like that you can chain some Linq like below.

```
IEnumerable<string> result = products
   .GroupBy(x => x.ProductName)
   .Select(product 
        => product.Key
           + new string(product
                       .SelectMany(x 
                                => ", " + x.IncrementalValue.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
                                    .ToArray()));
```

From here you can iterate through the result to get your desired output.

Comment: thank u so much for this. this works for me perfectly as well.